# Facebook like - Remove domain name in feed display

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm adding like button for every video a user uploads to my app.
The like button href is directed at "http://mydomain.com/redirector.aspx?id=[uniqueId]".
When the user likes a video, it all works as planned, but in the feed there's a line displaying the "mydomain.com" domain.
The client doesn't want to see that line, and I can't find a way to remove it.
This is the same line that when posting with fb.ui feed, can be removed via the "caption" property (I like to set it to "&-nbsp;".
I've tried placing "og:site_name" property in the redirector.aspx, but no luck here.
Has anyone ever had any luck with making this line disappear?
I want to point out that the problem is not about facebook scraper following the redirection, it does not. The problem is not knowing what og tag to use to make the domain line disappear.

Comment: _“I've tried placing "og:site_name" property in the redirector.aspx”_ – does not make sense there; since Facebook scraper will follow the redirect, the only OG meta tags that will count are those from the _target_ URL of the redirect.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I'll add that the redirector.aspx only does JS redirect, and does not contain "og:url" tag... So the scraper stays within the redirector.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

On the redirec URL, look for the useragent `facebookexternalhit/1.1`. If you see this, disable the redirect and display OG tags instead. For all other user-agents, leave the URL redirect intact. This will trick Facebook into scraping the OG tags on the redirect page without following the URL, and all other users will see the redirected URL.

I describe the process on [my website](https://www.webniraj.com/2011/06/30/let-facebook-scrape-password-protected-pages-for-like-buttons/), and I've used it for clients in the past. Once implemented, test the redirect URL using the Debug Tool to confirm it works.

Comment: Hi Niraj, first of all - thanks for taking the time to answer.
My problem is not about facebook following my redirection. I can see that it does not. My problem is making the domain line in the "like" display in the feed go away.

Comment: As far as I can see, the domain name / site name is always there when liking something off facebook.

Comment: @NirajShah were u able to remove the site name / domain name?

Comment: The domain cannot be hidden, but the idea was that you can use a redirect to mask the true domain by looking for the Facebook bot and servicing different content.